# Не срабатывает EventListener присвоенный через цикл

Tags: javascript, циклы, события

Низки поклон тому кто поможет. Проблема заключается в следующем: получаю через template макет HTML элемента li, затем добавляю его на страницу. В нём содержится кнопка с id="add". После добавления всех li  в список ul я получаю в NodeList все button посредством document.querySelectorAll('button#add'). После этого прогоняю полученный массив через цикл forEach присваивая addEventListener. Listener, в свою очередь, на отрез не реагирует. Сам цикл работает(проверял посредством вывода строки в консоль). При этом в EventListeners присвоенный listener на button отображается. При клике никакой реакции

```
      let templeate = document.getElementById("item").content;
      const readyItem = templeate.cloneNode(true);
      meals.appendChild(readyItem);
      const addersItem = document.querySelectorAll("button#add");

  addersItem.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log('done');
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const addersItem = document.querySelectorAll("button#add");
addersItem.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log('done', e.target.outerHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="add0">Button 0</button>
<button id="add">Button 1</button>
<button id="add">Button 2</button>
<button id="add">Button 3</button>
<button id="add4">Button 4</button>
```

Возможно, Вы [пере]создаете элементы *после* цикла назначения обработчиков события.

Comment: Когда уже люди запомнят про одинаковые id ?.. Это я не Вам, просто мысли вслух...

Comment: @UModeL Согласен. Но в данном случае дело в чем-то другом.

Comment: Убрал id у элементов, дабы было всё по красоте. Добавил им всем класс _add. Элементы не переназначаются, классы остаются теми же. Проблема не исчезла

Comment: Ага, выяснилось, что всё работает, но только в случае двойного клика...

Comment: @ГеоргийМедведев Вы видите, что в ответе все работает? Создайте в вопросе (кнопка "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса) пример, демонстрирующий то, что Вы наблюдаете.